# custom Size crystal report

Tags: c#-3.0

I have developed a custom size crystal report which is  25 in wide and 15 in  height.
this report is correctly seen in server side. but when I used to see it from clint side I can only see half. actually I have problem in custom size report only other reports are working correctly in clint and server both side. when I set report size greater the tabloid problem occours. I don't need to be print it. I have to only view. please any one can help me. this problem ruined my head.